# Play raw audio data BLOB

Tags: javascript, blob, html5-audio

One of our system has the capability to return a recording as blob data. The description from the documentation:

> A GET on an item returns the binary blob of the recording with Content-Type "audio/x-wav".

When I save this data to a wav file, it is playable, but I don't want to store is but use it this data to play the file from a website.

The data returned is raw data like:

```
RIFF�WAVEfmt 1@YA@factddataP͗�"���Ɩۖb�V�3Ԅe��8�W�@�đ#���h�"����o�ml��D�miG�F��Rˑ �YST@��I#i�S��TT��Dr�H@47.ݧ��M�D��$���-�9n�\+1� ���) ����)S�`\ő!I,�$��Y�`䘑$��#�P&��_�r����QE �i
```

I've tried converting this to a blob-URL, but without success. The data is fetched using PHP Curl.

Using:

```
file_put_contents('vm.wav', $API->getVoicemail(96));
```

will store the file and makes it playable. The code I used to make the blob data playable in an Audio Element is:

```
var wavString = "<? echo base64_encode($API->getVoicemail(96)) ?>";
// var wavString = "<? echo $API->getVoicemail(96) ?>"; // Alternative, but makes the script crash due to the symbols
var len = wavString.length;
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(len);
var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  view[i] = wavString.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
}
var blob = new Blob([view], {type: "audio/x-wav"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
console.log(url);
var wave = new Audio();
wave.controls = true;
wave.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(wave);
```

Unfortunately, no success... Any ideas how to get this to work?

Edit:

I've tried creating an extra file, called fetch.php, to which I set the  element as source. Beneath is the code:

```
<?php

$vmID = $_GET['id'];

$cvm = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cvm, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
curl_setopt($cvm, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.to.server/api/vms/". $vmID);
curl_setopt($cvm, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cvm, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($cvm, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$vmgetheaders = array();
$vmgetheaders[] = "Connection: close";
curl_setopt($cvm, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $vmgetheaders);

$vmgetresult = curl_exec($cvm);
if (curl_errno($cvm)) {
    $vmgetresult = 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($cvm); 

echo $vmgetresult;
?>
```

When browsing the fetch.php?id=1 page, the result is:

```
RIFF�WAVEfmt 1@YA@factddataP͗�"���Ɩۖb�V�3Ԅe��8�W�@�đ#���h�"����o�ml��D�miG�F��Rˑ �YST@��I#i�S��TT��Dr�H@47.ݧ��M�D��$���-�9n�\+1� ���) ����)S�`\ő!I,�$��Y�`䘑$��#�P&��_�r����QE �i
```

But when trying it in an  element, nothing happens. Here's the code I use for the element:

```
<audio src="https://url/fetch.php?id=96" controls>
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

No errors appear in the console of network tab, as well as no PHP errors occur.

Comment: can't you just create an `<audio>` element whose source is the URL to the wav file / blob data?

Comment: I have to fetch the data first using php curl. The returned data can be used. So I can't use the URL.

Comment: it can if you make a PHP script which does nothing except fetch the request blob data via curl and return it directly to the client. (P.S. Alternatively...whatever curl calls will be a URL...is there anything stopping you calling that URL directly from the browser?)

Comment: It was a nice idea, but just tried it and nothing happens. Created a file called fetch.php. Call it using fetch.php?id=96. The script reads the id, fetches the data and echos it.

Comment: ok. And you made this the target of an `<audio>` control? Can you show the code of exactly what you did (both HTML and PHP)? Also post any errors or warnings from both the browser's console and network tabs, or from the PHP.

Comment: Alternatively, since you were trying to go down the base64 route in your original code, here's a super-simple example of an `<audio>` control using a base64 string as its source (view the source of the page to see the HTML): https://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/audio.php

Comment: Edited the post with the requested information. Also tried the link with the base64 encoding. No succes with this as well... Other option could be linking directly to the API server, as putting the request URL in the browser result in downloading a playable WAV file, except there authentication required for accessing the info.

Comment: Unfortunately the authentication would likely be an issue for that approach I think. In the PHP try setting the content type header appropriately to "audio/x-wav" and see if that helps. Do you just get an empty audio control at the moment?

Comment: Unfortunately, also setting the content-type to audio/x-wav doesn't fix it...

Comment: So you just get an empty audio control? Is the file definitely valid? Temporarily just download the file to your webserver, place it there as a .wav and point the audio control's src to that directly and see if that helps. Also, what browser are you testing with? Not all support WAV in an audio control. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: Ah, that seems to be an issue. Windows Media player does play it, but other players refuse this with an error: Unsupported file format, though they should support WAV files.

Comment: I just noticed that it does work on mobile devices, but not on my desktop... I'll just let it go for now. Maybe in a further stage, I'll try to do something about it.

Comment: It depends more on the specific browser you use I think, rather than the operating system. Obviously on mobile devices and O/Ses you get different editions of the browsers, even if they're branded the same (e.g. Chrome) it's actually a somewhat different codebase. There's a compatibility table in that link I gave you which shows you which browser support which audio and video formats. One obvious thing which stands out for instance is that Internet Explorer does not support WAV files at all within the `<audio>` element.

Comment: I would try `audio/wav` as the content type